# How to install Token Macro Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins

New Jenkins user here, I've been using it for about a month for a data warehouse project, installed quite a lot of plugins via the upload method, but cannot figure out how to install Token Macro Plugin, it is a dependency for another plugin I want, but it has no instructions and the download is not similar to the other plugins I've used, please enlighten me.

Comment: an alternative to the install via jenkins/pluginManager/available (if you do not have have http proxy set up due to security restrictions like me :D) is going to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/ , downloading the hpi file for your plugin and uploading via jenkins/pluginManager/advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see [this youtube to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO78YL3HCEk) on how to install any plugin on Jenkins using the interface.

And according to the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Installingthenewestversion) it's the simplest way to install a macro-plugin without contemplating about the prerequisites.